# Запятая и тире

Tags: и, пунктуация

Есть предложение: "Не важно,  как умереть – важно, как жить".

Как здесь объяснить отсутствие запятой? Предложение в таком виде смотрится нормально, но тогда получается, что тире поглощает запятую. С точки зрения грамматики и интонации, можно объяснить так: сообщение состоит только из двух фраз, придаточные интонационно не выделяются (поэтому и нет  запятой), старшая структура всего предложения строится на противопоставлении (союз А пропущен, его заменяет тире).

А что по поводу оформления этого предложения можно найти в классических правилах?

Answer (score 1):

У Лопатина:§ 132. В сложных синтаксических конструкциях, распадающихся на крупные логико-синтаксические блоки, которые сами по себе являются сложными предложениями или в которых один из блоков оказывается сложным предложением, на стыке блоков ставятся знаки препинания, указывающие на взаимоотношения блоков, при сохранении внутренних знаков, поставленных на своем собственном синтаксическом основании:

Здесь два блока из СПП, между ними тире, отражающее антонимичные отношения ССП, а внутри них запятые, как положено.

http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=136#pp136

Comment: Тогда получается, что запятую надо ставить? В книге запятой не было. "Не важно, как умереть, – важно, как жить". Но без запятой предложение выглядит намного изящнее, лучше выражает смысл, да и интонация у двух вариантов разная. И тогда,соответственно, вопрос: а тире вообще-то в каких-либо случаях может поглощать запятую?

Comment: Нет, запятой нет, потому что на стыке блоков только тире. Запятая внутри блоков:" (Не важно, как умереть) – (важно, как жить)".Здесь не поглощение запятой, здесь каждый блок как отдельно взятое предложение, только первое без знака конца, ведь два предл. объединили в одно.

Comment: Спасибо. А есть ли где-нибудь в правилах похожие примеры, на которые можно сослаться?

Comment: Лопатин в примерах приводит двоеточие и точку с запятой, тире нет. Надо искать в худ. текстах, но мне  некогда. Если это Вам нужно,забейте в поисковик "Примеры сложных синтаксических конструкций с антонимичными связями"

Answer (score 1):

Процитированный § 132 Лопатина к данному случаю не подходит, он о распадении предложения на КРУПНЫЕ БЛОКИ, что и подтверждают примеры, то есть в основном о точке с запятой.

Думаю, запятая здесь нужна.

Розенталь: Тире в сложноподчиненном предложении ставится после запятой, закрывающей придаточную часть, **для усиления пунктуации**, **при «переломе» конструкции**, **перед словом *это*** **и т. д.**

*Он замолчал, но не потому, что ему не хватало слов, — ему не хватало дыхания.*

*В смущении он говорил не то, что думал, — он произносил первые пришедшие на ум слова.*

Comment: tat, дело не в том, что это КРУПНЫЕ блоки, а в том,что их структура логически цельная, завершённая,равная по смыслу отдельной синтагме.В сложном предложении с разными видами связи главное - расставить логические акценты с помощью знаков препинания.Вот у Лихачёва: "Когда называют Питер столицей, я не возражаю, потому что  это подтягивает город - он как бы становится чище и лучше."Здесь нет крупных блоков, но автор вместо запятой поставил тире, чтобы подчеркнуть отношения следствия, а запятая должна бы быть,чтобы закрыть придаточное, однако тире её поглотило, его оказалось достаточно.

Comment: Людмила, а не кажется ли Вам, что в Вашем примере после слов "это подтягивает город" происходит не поглощение запятой посредством тире, а просто вместо запятой стоит тире, так как имеется оттенок следствия, а не перечислительное значение?

Comment: Tat, я думаю, что в ваших примерах запятая ставится по обычному принципу независимой постановки знаков препинания. Придаточное выделяется интонационно и запятыми, я не вижу  логически противопоставленных блоков, которые могут повлиять на отсутствие запятой.  Здесь противопоставление не является старшей структурой, противопоставляются  только придаточные части.

Comment: Людмила, в вашем примере тире стоит ВМЕСТО запятой между однородными придаточными. Тире может стоять и между блоками сложного предложения смешанного типа, но оно не отменяет запятой, закрывающей придаточное, потому что не влияет на пунктуацию в блоках. Тире между блоками ставится на своем основании, а запятая после придаточного - на своем. Если не закрыть придаточное, то тем самым мы отнесем последующий блок к придаточному, что неправильно. В обсуждаемом примере получается "как умереть – важно".

Comment: Сравните со вставными конструкциями. Мы закрываем оборот в конце вставной конструкции, несмотря на то, что после него стоит тире.